# Value of <Input in Vue component not getting value of method

Tags: vuejs2

I have a list of users. Click on a specific user the user edit form is populated but the only way I can get a value in the input is by putting the return in the
 `<input v-model="this.cl.data.USER_RLTNP_SCTY_ACCS_GRP.User_Name" ref=User_Name>`

if I do
 `<input v-model="User_Name "v-bind:value="this.cl.data.USER_RLTNP_SCTY_ACCS_GRP.User_Name">`

Nothing appears in the input.

If I use the v-model="this.cl.data....." the value of the user_name is in the input I'm not sure how the value is passed to my updateUser() function because normally I would use username = this.User_Name

Using apollo and Graphgl for the querying

> ```
> <template> 
>   <div>   
>   <v-text-field label="User Name" ref="User_Name" v-model="User_Name" v-bind:value="this.cl.data.USER_RLTNP_SCTY_ACCS_GRP[0].User_Name" id="" placeholder="User Name"></v-text-field> 
>  <v-btn v-on:click="editUser()">Edit</v-btn>
> </div>
> </template>
>
> <script>
> import gql from graphql-tag import { SCTY_ACCS_GRP, SCTY_ACCS_GRP_USER }  
> from './gqlqueries'
>
> export default {
>
> data: () => ({
>     users: [], 
>     cl: '',
>     user_form: false, 
>     user_name: ''
>
> }),
>
> methods: {
>     editForm: async function(userid){ 
>         this.cl = await this.$apollo.query({query : SCTY_ACCS_GRP_USER, variables:  {id : userid}})
>         this.user_form = true
>         console.log(this.cl)
>         alert(this.cl.data.USER_RLTNP_SCTY_ACCS_GRP[0].User_Name)
>
>     }, 
>     editUser(){
>         this.user_name = this.User_Name
>         alert(this.user_name)
>     }
> },
>
> mounted: async function() {
>     this.users = await this.$apollo.query({ query: SCTY_ACCS_GRP })
>   //  console.log(this.users.data.USER_RLTNP_SCTY_ACCS_GRP)
> }   } 
> </script>
> ```

I would assume the `<input v-bind:value="this.cl.data....">` Would populate once The `editForm()` function is triggered. So how do I get the value of the User_Name when the editUser button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

You could try [list rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html).
A little example :

https://jsfiddle.net/L4xu9r5g/7/

```js
 


var mapp = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    currentuserinfo : undefined,
    users: [
      { name: "John Doe", id :  12},
      { name: "Black Jack", id : 932},
      { name: "White Jack", id: 342}
    ],
    userinfo: 
        [
        { userid: 12, favcolor: 'green', age : 23},
      { userid: 932, favcolor: 'red', age : 11},
      { userid: 342, favcolor: 'blue', age : 12}
    ]
  },
  methods: 
  {
   selectuser : function(id) 
   {
   //your query here
   this.currentuserinfo = this.userinfo.filter(u => u.userid ==id)[0];
   
   }
  }
})
```

```css
td, th 
{
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Select User</th>
  </tr>
<tr v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
<td>{{user.name}}</td>
<td><button @click="selectuser(user.id)">Select User</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div v-if="currentuserinfo === undefined">
Please select a user
</div>
<div v-if="currentuserinfo != undefined">
<span>Favourite color : {{currentuserinfo.favcolor}}</span><br/>
<span>Age : {{currentuserinfo.age}}</span><br/>
</div>
</div>
```